# Creating dynamically methods in R6Class, magic of print(ls.str())

Tags: r, r6

In R, I wanted to create a class (R6Class) that when calling initialize creates few dynamic methods (the number of methods and its names depends on parameters in initialize). But I get into strange problem with environments.

Here is a simplified version of code that doesn't work.

```
library(R6)

ffactory <- function(i) {
  function() i
}

A <- R6Class(
  lock_objects=FALSE,
  public=list(
    initialize=function(args) {
      for (i in args) {
        self[[i]] <- ffactory(i)
      }
    }
  )
)

a <- A$new(c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Now:

```
> a$a()
[1] "c"
> a$b()
[1] "c"
> a$c()
[1] "c"
```

In order to find what was wrong I had added a line that prints environment in ffactory function. That is

```
ffactory <- function(i) {
  print(ls.str())
  function() i
}
```

And now it has started to work!!!

```
> a$a()
[1] "a"
> a$b()
[1] "b"
> a$c()
[1] "c"
```

So why? There should be something I don't understand. Observer effect or what? :)

What is the magic of the line `print(ls.str())`? Actually I cannot remove neither `print` nor `str` from this line. Of course it is so silly to have  a line like that. Not to mention garbage on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encountered lazy evaluation - R waits as long as it is able to before evaluating `i` - and in the former case, `i` will be evaluated at its last value in all instances. There's nothing really special about the combination of `print` and `ls.str`; anything that forces `i` to be evaluated prior to your method calls (`a$a()`, `a$b()`, etc...) will do the same.

Formally, this is what `force` is used for:

```
ffactory <- function(i) {
  force(i);
  function() i
}

R> a$a()
#[1] "a"
R> a$b()
#[1] "b"
R> a$c()
#[1] "c"
```

However, this also happens to do the job:

```
ffactory <- function(i) {
  #force(i);
  .z <- capture.output(cat(i, "\n"))
  function() i
}

R> a$a()
#[1] "a"
R> a$b()
#[1] "b"
R> a$c()
#[1] "c"
```

---

There are presumably countless ways to force evaluation; I would argue that using `force` makes your intention most clear, though.

Quoting the help file directly,

> force forces the evaluation of a formal argument. This can be useful
>   if the argument will be captured in a closure by the lexical scoping
>   rules and will later be altered by an explicit assignment or an
>   implicit assignment in a loop or an apply function.

and subsequently,

> This is semantic sugar: just evaluating the symbol will do the same
>   thing (see the examples).

In fact, looking at how `force` is defined,

```
R> force
#function (x) 
#  x
#<bytecode: 0x3b7b528>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

You could even get away with

```
ffactory <- function(i) {
  i; function() i
}
```

But as noted, I think the explicitly calling `force` will make your code more readable.

Comment: Hehehe. Thanks a lot! It sort of funny to have lazy argument `i` inside lazy evaluated function `function() i` that is inside a non-lazy evaluated function.

Comment: Sure, feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.